# Unable to align one Image button right while the other one the left

Tags: android, android-layout

This the xml in which I am trying to keep one image button on the right and while the left ? 
I dont why it is not happening though i have set the grvaity too ?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="fill">
           <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_button_left"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_button_right"      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you do not want the button backgrounds to stretch?

Comment: yes , that is the correct assumption

Comment: Have you had any success? The RelativeLayout post by rekaszeru should have done the trick.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and set the `layout_alignParentRight` attribute for the second `ImageButton` to `true`:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

so your layout would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="fill">
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_button_left" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2" 
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_button_right" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I agree with this post, except that you need to set the RelativeLayout's height and width to fill_parent and you'd probably want to set the first button to layout_alignParentLeft="true" as well.

Comment: Sure, but only in case that this RelativeLayout isn't a renderer for say a row in a `ListView`. I believe @Huzaifa has the reasons to have its layout params set this way (although, i agree with your `layout_width="fill_parent"` comment). By default the items in a RelativeLayout are aligned top|left, so it's not necessary to set it explicitly for the first `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 1):

You set `LinearLayout`'s width to `wrap_content` so it has a minimal width to place buttons inside itself. There's no way these button can be aligned just because they have no space for alignment. Try setting `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

may be you forget android:orientation="horizontal" in LinearLayout if you have used width to wrap_content.

Else Relativle layout as stated above is perfect for you.